# Update foreach()'s iterator inside itself

Tags: php, laravel

Is there an easy way in PHP to add more iteration in a `foreach()` loop?

Example:

```
$iterator = [1, 2, 3];

foreach($iterator as $item){
    echo $item;
    $iterator = [1, 2, 3, 4]; // Update the foreach()'s iterator here from database!
}


// Actual Output: 123
// Desired Output: 1234
```

P.S the actual iterator is a Laravel Eloquent object, so I can't simply use `for()` instead

Answer (score 0):

Use recursive function

```
   function iteration($array) {
      foreach ($array as $item) {
        echo $item;
        $new_array = fetch(); // function to fetch elements
        if (!empty($new_array)) { // your condition here whether the new iteration shall be called
          iteration($new_array);
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Looks like an infinite loop :)

Comment: Sure, it depends on how do you fetch new array elements. There shall be some checks, but it's blackbox for us as by OP "Update the foreach()'s iterator here from database!". However I've made an edit with simple check.